# Suggestd Crash due to SGSqliteDatabaseError

Tags: macos, nfs, ldap

I'm currently working in an environment with some Openldap users and nfs mounted homes. Everything is working like a charm, but I'm facing some issues regarding some ReportCrash that keeps writing in the users `/home/user/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` thousands of logs `suggestd_2017-07-12-095040_e5r1p1.crash`

When I give a look in /var/log/system.log, it's completely saturated with ReportCrash [full log here](https://pastebin.com/LjTY0f4Z)

> suggestd[2792]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'SGSqliteDatabaseError', reason: 'Error(5): database is locked (SQL:
>   PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL)'

I'm wondering how to perhaps, unlocked that SQLite database ? or simply disable suggestd to write down files every 10 seconds.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7264893?start=15&tstart=0

I've tried to unload theses services, with no changes at all.
I'm looking to either fix that "crash", or simply disable that suggestd once and for all.

Comment: Hi - why the NFS and ldap tags? Is there a back story to your setup or a relation to the crash that we're missing?

Comment: This only occurs when a user is log into the machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to unload the daemon:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.suggestd.plist
```